# Acentuação de arquivos na leitura de diretório

Tags: php

Criei uma leitura de diretórios simples no PHP, só que na hora que envio arquivos com acentuação, eles aparecem com caracteres estranhos e depois não consigo abrir esses arquivos.

Como fazer a leitura correta da acentuação?

Já tentei um um monte de coisas mudando para UTF8 no HTML, mas até agora nada.

```
 <?php
    //diretorio
    $base = 'files/';
    $abreDir = ($_GET['dir'] != '' ? $_GET['dir'] : $base);
    $openDir = dir($abreDir);            
    //voltar
    $strrdir = strrpos(substr($abreDir,0,-1),'/');
    $voltar = substr($abreDir,0,$strrdir+1);

    $openDir = dir($abreDir);                 
       while($arq = $openDir -> read()):
            if($arq != '.' && $arq != '..'):
                if(is_dir($abreDir.$arq)):
                    //pastas                                                        
                    echo'<li class="folders"><a href="discovirtual?dir='.$abreDir.$arq.'/">'.$arq.'</a></li>';          
                else:
                    //arquivos     
                    echo'<li class="files"><a href="'.$abreDir.$arq.'">'.$arq.'</a></li>';                              
                endif;                      
            endif;              
       endwhile;
    if($abreDir != $base):
        echo '<a href="discovirtual?dir='. $voltar.'">Voltar</a>';
    endif;
    $openDir -> close();
?>
```

Comment: O problema é na listagem ou na hora que você clica no link para abrir um arquivo? Nesse último caso, o arquivo está sendo servidor diretamente pelo seu webserver (apache?), e você precisa configurar o encoding padrão para servir cada tipo de arquivo. Mesmo assim pode não adiantar, já que pode haver no disco arquivos do mesmo tipo com encodings diferentes...

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado por responder.

Na hora que renomeio ele com acentuação, ele passa o arquivo para ser aberto com acentuação no navegador, sendo assim não consigo visualizar o arquivo.

E quando envio o arquivo com acentuação para o servidor, na hora visualizo na minha listagem ele me exibe com caracteres estranho como triangulos e etc...

Amigos eu não sei como inserir os decods... como eu faria colocaria utf8_decode na variável, tem alguma dica...

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras para solucionar. A que mais recomendo é `renomear os arquivos` com um `hash` em `sha1` ou tirar os acentos na hora da inclusão. Isso resolverá os problemas com acentos e caracteres especiais.

Outra forma de converter esses caracteres que citou é usando `utf8_decode();` ou `utf8_encode();`

O que elas fazem?

> `utf8_encode` — Codifica um string ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8
>
> `utf8_decode` — Converte uma string com caracteres ISO-8859-1
>   codificadas com UTF-8 para single-byte ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado por responder.

Na hora que renomeio ele com acentuação, ele passa o arquivo para ser aberto com acentuação no navegador, sendo assim não consigo visualizar o arquivo.

E quando envio o arquivo com acentuação para o servidor, na hora visualizo na minha listagem ele me exibe com caracteres estranho como triangulos e etc...

Amigos eu não sei como inserir os decods... como eu faria colocaria utf8_decode na variável, tem alguma dica...

Obrigado

Comment: Normalmente eu vou com os dois pés no peito de quem sugere o uso de de utf8_encode() / utf8_decode() (risos), mas nesse caso em particular, relamente é a melhor, pra não dizer única, saída, já que até o tão prometido PHP 6, o PHP não suporta operações Unicode.

Comment: Eu tive uma idéia, vou criar uma função para remover acentuações a e caracterss maiusculos e substituir espaços por traços como numa url amigavel... vamos ver se consigo. Assim que tiver uma resposta posto aqui o resultado. Obrigado pelas repostas.