# Listar arquivos de uma pasta / diretório em PHP de determinadas extensões

Tags: php, diretório

Preciso listar os arquivos de uma pasta, e exibi-los pelo nome *linkado* ao diretório dele para *download*.

Uso esse código:

```
$pasta = 'uploads/';
$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($arquivos as $img){
   echo $img;
}
```

Até aí tudo bem. mas ele exibe o diretório e o arquivo completo assim:

```
uploads/editail1.jpg
```

e eu queria que ele exibisse apenas o nome do arquivo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Navegação em pastas no PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83521/navega%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-pastas-no-php)

Comment: @DanielOmine Aquela é recursiva, voltada a árvores de diretório e não pastas simples. Achei importante ter uma resposta específica e objetiva para pastas. Imagino que seja muito mais facil adaptar esta aqui para um usuário que precisa de uma solução simples do que alguém entender o que remover daquela. EM TEMPO: não acho que você votou errado, apenas entendo que o problema é suficientemente diferente para serem perguntas separadas. Mas seja lá o que a comunidade decidir, está bem decidido.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usando seu código:

```
chdir( 'pasta_desejada' );
$arquivos = glob("{*.png,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.bmp,*.gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($arquivos as $img) echo $img;
```

Usando as funções padrão para diretórios do PHP:

```
$types = array( 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' );
if ( $handle = opendir('pasta_desejada') ) {
    while ( $entry = readdir( $handle ) ) {
        $ext = strtolower( pathinfo( $entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) );
        if( in_array( $ext, $types ) ) echo $entry;
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Tem esta possibilidade também:

```
$types = array( 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' );
$path = 'pasta_desejada';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
    $ext = strtolower( $fileInfo->getExtension() );
    if( in_array( $ext, $types ) ) echo $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```

Veja os 3 trechos de código funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/gIdgBf)**.

**Notas:**

- No PHP < 5.3.6, o 3º exemplo precisa ser alterado:

  ```
  $ext = strtolower( pathinfo( $fileInfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION) );
  ```
- No caso do 2º e 3º exemplos, não ponha a mesma extensão em maiúsculas e minúsculas. Apenas minúsculas, pois o `strtolower` já está normalizando as extensões dos arquivos.

Comment: Funcionou certo, só que queria que me auxiliasse em mais um detalhe, eu linkei o arquivo para download. só que dá erro quando o arquivo tem caracteres especiais tipo. (PREG�O%20PRESENCIAL.jpg). como faço para resolver? já apliquei a conversão para UTF-8. mudou, mas não resolveu.

Comment: Essa pergunta aqui fala disso, acho que já vi outras com esse assunto também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15723 - Mas a verdade é uma só: sempre vai dar um monte de problema. O certo é gravar sempre sem acento, e tudo em minúsculas. Dá um pouco de trabalho a mais na hora de implementar, mas é muito mais simples do que toda hora ter que ficar arrumando. Cada hospedagem e OS se comporta de um jeito, não tem solução boa com acentos no arquivo.