# Fazer com que o PHP leia as pastas do servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Colegas.

Peguei agora um projeto aqui no trabalho, onde lá nos primórdios esse projeto foi desenvolvido. Funciona da seguinte forma:

Foi criado na página index.php algumas pastas com jpg, onde direciona para os respectivos links. Porém os arquivos (PDF) são enviados enviados via FTP, onde o setor aqui do trabalho cria pastas e subpastas e coloca esses arquivos PDF.

A pessoa que fez esse "projeto" alterava apenas o link da imagem jpg na página inicial. Pensei em refazer esse projeto, só que já existe dezenas de pastas e subpastas com esses arquivos pdf.

Quando clicamos no link das pastas, aparece a página index/of e o nome do arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pensei em fazer, criar um arquivo em html ou PHP, personalizar e ver se com o PHP, JQuery, Ajax, não sei ao certo, lia nos nomes das pastas/subpastas do servidor e criar algo mais personalizado com imagem ao lado do nome do arquivo ou algo nesse sentido.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: "*são enviados **viados** via FTP*" - kkkkkkk

Comment: Penso que ele quer listar todos os PDF's que estão nas respectivas pastas dinâmicamente, sem ter que adicionar o link manualmente no ficheiro `index`. Pelo que percebi, haverá um problema, as imagens na lista atual é associada manualmente ao PDF (não está dentro da mesma que o respectivo PDF), ou está? Só ele pode responder.

Comment: Filipe, exatamente isso. A pessoa abre o FTP, cria as pastas e joga o PDF dentro. Em muitos casos, cria-se também subpastas.

Comment: Olá Guilherme. O arquivo PHP estará dentro do servidor, mas fora das pastas e subpastas, na pasta raiz.

Comment: @Fox.11 é isso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108662/3635?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desta forma?
Nesse caso ele seleciona a pasta e retorna as sub-pastas existentes nela.
Se for, estude um pouco sobre. **[DirectoryIterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php)**

```
<?php
    // atribuição a variável $dir
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator( './pasta/' );

    // atribui o valor de $dir para $file em loop
    foreach($dir as $file ) {
        // verifica se o valor de $file é diferente de '.' ou '..'
        // e é um diretório (isDir)
        if (!$file->isDot() && $file->isDir()) { 
            // atribuição a variável $dname
            $dname = $file->getFilename();

            // imprime o nome do diretório
            echo $dname."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: +1 Não conhecia essa daí não. Valeu, @PedroQuezado!!!

Comment: Sério, seria muito bom para a comunidade e interessante para todos se pudessem realmente marcar a pergunta como dup, ao invés de ficarem gerando respostas repetitivas de algo que já foi perguntando dezenas de vezes, isso traria um enorme beneficio para toda comunidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Listar+arquivos

Answer (score -1):

Eu testei ***[esse código daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php)*** e serviu perfeitamente.

```
<?php

function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($ffs as $ff) {
        if ($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
listFolderFiles('/websites/');
```

Comment: Sério, seria muito bom para a comunidade e interessante para todos se pudessem realmente marcar a pergunta como dup, ao invés de ficarem gerando respostas repetitivas de algo que já foi perguntando dezenas de vezes, isso traria um enorme beneficio para toda comunidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Listar+arquivos

Comment: *Let's do this*