# Fazer o PHP mostrar os arquivos da pasta

Tags: php, post

Galera, estou trabalhando em meu projeto. Um app de leitura.

Mas quero fazer uma coisa para ajudar nele, eu tenho mais de 12000 pdf's para botar no aplicativo.

Eu queria que eu colocasse o pdf na pasta  ele aparecesse do jeito que esta mostrado noa foto abaixo

Ou o metodo usado aí e um post? me ajudem

***obs*** tipo assim 
[image: Exemplo de como eu quero]

Comment: Dá pra fazer listando os arquivos do diretório, sim! A questão é que essa não é nem de longe a melhor maneira de se fazer isso. Uma boa maneira seria renomear todos os PDFs colocando neles nomes simples, sem espacos, acentuações, caracteres especiais e de prefência, nomes randomicos para evitar colisão, exemplo: 31af03ba111d8c38a3be9936c9c427ba.pdf e aí você usaria um banco de dados para fazer o cadastro de todo o acervo, linkando o nome do arquivo com o título cadastrado no banco. Essa é uma boa maneira. A questão é: você está afim de ter todo esse trabalho para ter um sistema melhor?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Listar arquivos de uma pasta / diretório em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108662/listar-arquivos-de-uma-pasta-diret%c3%b3rio-em-php)

Comment: e como eu poderia fazer isso? :D nao sei muita coisa kk

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo para listar os arquivos (de um determinado tipo) em um diretório.

```
chdir( 'path' );
$files = glob("{*.pdf,}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) echo $file;
```

Lembrando que como comentádo, essa não é a melhor maneira para uma solução como a sua. ;)