# Como listar arquivos de um diretório e depois compará-los com uma lista de arquivos permitidos usando PHP?

Tags: php

Estou com um problema que estou quebrando a cabeça pra resolver.

Como faço para listar os arquivos de um diretório e depois compará-los com uma lista de arquivos permitidos usando PHP?

A intenção disso é excluir os arquivos que não estão nesta lista de permitidos.
Tentei (e ainda estou tentando) fazer isso usando o "DirectoryIterator" do php e estou fazendo testes também com o "scandir", mais tudo sem sucesso até agora.

Queria saber se isso é possível de ser feito. Acredito que a dificuldade nisso está na comparação entre arrays (arquivos permitidos e não permitidos) e a conversão dos valores de cada posição desses arrays para variáveis que podem ser tratadas.

Como sou iniciante no assunto queria a ajuda de vocês para tentar resolver esse problema.

Não posto aqui o código que estou testando pois não tem nada conciso nele (não ia ser de grande ajuda).

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: por favor, poste o código que você esta usando juntamente com o erro gerado.

Comment: Marquei como ampla demais pois pede 2 coisas distintas.
Uma delas encontra resposta aqui, que é como listar arquivos de um diretório: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108662 Se você já sabe fazer isso que é algo simples, poderia ser mais objetivo na pergunta e perguntar somente como comparar dois arrays ou coisa do tipo. E provavelmente já tem também resposta para isso. Pesquise no site que encontrará tudo que precisa. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+comparar+array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá! Para validar verdadeiramente o tipo de arquivo, não se pode apenas confiar na extensão do nome (*.pdf, *.xls, etc). É preciso **ler os primeiros bytes do arquivo** e compará-los a padrões esperados. Para alguns tipos mais comuns o PHP tem algumas constantes. Para todos os demais é preciso formular manualmente a comparação.

Neste exemplo, uma função avalia um arquivo que é submetido via `post` (mas você pode simplesmente carregar o arquivo via `file_get_contents()`). Nela, são permitidos apenas os tipos arquivo PDF, imagem JPG ou JPEG (não importa a extensão) e imagem PNG.

```
public function validar_arquivo() {
    // Valida o arquivo enviado, e quando incorreto retorna false
    if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])) {
        // Valida o tamanho, 3145728 bytes = 3072 kB = 3 MB
        if($_FILES['arquivo']['size'] > 3145728) {
            echo('O tamanho do arquivo deve ser inferior ou igual a 3,00 MB.');  
            return false;
        }

        // Valida o conteúdo do arquivo
        if($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']) {
            $file_data = file_get_contents($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
            if(substr($file_data, 0, 6) == '%PDF-1') {
                echo('application/pdf');
            } else if(exif_imagetype($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
                echo('image/jpeg');
            } else if(exif_imagetype($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                echo('image/png');
            } else {
                echo('O arquivo enviado não está no formato esperado: arquivo PDF, imagem JPG ou imagem PNG.');  
                return false;
            }
        }

    }   
    return true;
}
```

O PDF precisou ser comparado manualmente com `'%PDF-1'`, já para as imagens o PHP tinha as constantes `IMAGETYPE_JPEG` e `IMAGETYPE_PNG`.

Como referência dos formatos, consulte a página: http://filext.com/, como por exemplo em http://filext.com/file-extension/JPG.

Comment: Olá @C. Bohok!  
Obrigado pela força, seu código fez eu enchergar um nível mais refinado de validação de arquivos, e com toda certeza vai ser muito útil nos meus projetos.