# Renomear arquivos em de um diretório usando nomes já definidos através PHP

Tags: php

Preciso renomear mais de mil arquivos com a extensão .bmp localizados em um diretório "screen".

Os arquivos a serem renomeados seguem essa lógica "2017-08-06 19-29-58.bmp", "2017-08-06 19-29-59.bmp", "2017-08-06 19-30-00.bmp"... de acordo com sua dada de criação.

Já tenho um nome para cada um desses arquivos, mas os novos nomes não seguem uma sequência, por exemplo: o arquivo "2017-08-06 19-29-58.bmp" passará a ser chamado de "Conjunto Branco.bmp", o arquivo seguinte "2017-08-06 19-29-59.bmp" será renomeado para "Conjunto Preto.bmp", o próximo arquivo "2017-08-06 19-30-00.bmp" passará a ser "Conjunto Vermelho.bmp" e assim por diante.

Não sei como especificar através de código PHP para que a página da web verifique todos os arquivos listados no diretório "screen" e os renomeie de acordo com minha lista de nomes já definidos (array).

Comment: Se você terá que definir manualmente todos os nomes dos arquivos, não é mais fácil renomeá-los direto?

Comment: É que posso definir os nomes através do Excel, algumas partes do nome serão fixas. Sempre que eu tiver que renomear um novo lote, precisarei apenas trocar uma palavra, usando o exemplo mencionado, trocaria "Conjunto" por "Peças", futuramente por "Partes"... mas vou repetir o processo muitas vezes, por isso não seria bom fazer manualmente.

Comment: @Isac sua não sei se consegue ver este comentário, mas consegui adaptar sua resposta que foi removida, e ela seria a solução para meu problema. Alguém a removeu e não consigo mais visualizá-la.

Comment: @Wesley Fui eu que a removi pois aparentemente não vai de encontro ao que pretende. Teria que a reescrever de acordo com os seus objetivos, mas terá que ser bem mais especifico neles.Para além disso parece me uma solução propicia a erro.

Comment: @Isac Entendo, mas posso trabalhar em conjunto com esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108663/33945, eu vou pegar os nomes através do PHP e inseri-los no Excel para ordenar como preciso, e em conjunto com a formula Concatenar, criar a array completa automaticamente. Infelizmente você removeu a resposta antes que eu pudesse copiar o código passado :(

Comment: @Wesley Voltei a colocar a resposta para que possa ver o código que tinha, e aproveitei também para adicionar a lógica que eu penso que estava á procura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tem nomes predefinidos para a origem e destino pode utilizar um array com chave para o nome antigo e valor para o novo nome, e renomear através da função de `rename`.

Exemplo:

```
$caminhoBase = "/algumaPasta/"; //ou usar ./ para a pasta onde corre este arquivo php

//A chave é o nome antigo e o valor é o novo
$renomeacoes = Array(
"2017-08-06 19-29-58.bmp" => "Conjunto Branco.bmp",
"2017-08-06 19-29-59.bmp" => "Conjunto Preto.bmp",
"2017-08-06 19-30-00.bmp" => "Conjunto Vermelho.bmp");

//para cada elemento do array fazer a renomeação
foreach($renomeacoes as $antigo => $novo){
    rename("$caminhoBase$antigo","$caminhoBase$novo");
}
```

Se em vez disso, tem apenas a lista de novos nomes a atribuir e quer renomear com base na ordem dos ficheiros já será necessário obter a lista de ficheiros com `readdir` verificar a extensão e renomear um a um com base no array:

```
$caminhoBase = "./";  //diretorio de leitura dos arquivos

//agora só os novos
$novosNomes = Array(
    "Conjunto Branco.bmp",
    "Conjunto Preto.bmp",
    "Conjunto Vermelho.bmp");

if ($handle = opendir($caminhoBase)) { //abrir o diretorio
    $i = 0;

    while (false !== ($arquivo = readdir($handle))) { //percorrer os arquivos do diretorio

        if (strpos($arquivo, ".bmp")){ //ver se é .bmp
            rename ($caminhoBase . $arquivo, $caminhoBase . $novosNomes[$i++]);
            if ($i >= count($novosNomes)){ //se já esgotou os nomes do array sai do while
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema nesse caso é depender de ter os nomes, pois os arquivos possuem um intervalo (data de criação utilizada como nome) aleatório entre um e outro. É possível adaptar para que o PHP examine os arquivos já existentes e os defina como chave automaticamente em ordem alfabética crescente?

Comment: @Wesley Secalhar percebi mal a pergunta. Então os nomes existentes são aleatórios é isso ? mas são todos os arquivos que estão num diretório? e como sabe quais são os que são para renomear? e como estabelece a relação entre eles ?

Comment: Os nomes são gerados automaticamente de acordo com a data de criação, no exemplo 2017-08-06 19-29-58, indica que foi criado em 06 de agosto de 2017 às 19:29:58, todas imagens seguirão esse mesmo formato, baseando-se no momento em que foram criadas. São todos arquivos .bmp localizados em um só diretório. A relação estabeleci da seguinte maneira: seguindo a ordem alfabética, o primeiro arquivo sempre receberá o nome "Conjunto Preto", o segundo arquivo "Conjunto Branco, o terceiro "Conjunto Vermelho" e assim por diante. Desculpe não ter me expressado corretamente.

Comment: @Wesley Mas o primeiro arquivo é o primeiro listado por ordem alfabética numa pasta ? Isso parece me um pouco propicio a erro e difícil de acertar com a sua lista de novos nomes construída manualmente. Posso no entanto alterar o código para isso se é mesmo esse o objetivo

Comment: é sim, aplicando o filtro do próprio Windows, ordenando a exibição da pasta, o primeiro arquivo é o velho. Como o nome dos arquivos são iguais suas respectivas datas de criação, o PHP poderia se basear também na data de criação do arquivo, assim seria indiferente o nome utilizado, correto?

Comment: @Wesley nem por isso, porque a leitura é feita pelo php e tem de ser feita com a função [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readdir.php), que lê pela ordem estabelecida pelo sistema operativo.  Naturalmente pode tentar construir uma ordem com base nos resultados, ordenando e aplicando lógica por cima, mas já complica consideravelmente

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta e adaptação, no segundo exemplo funciona exatamente como desejado. Vou ficar de olho se não existe nenhum erro como você está preocupado, por em quanto é isso mesmo. Obrigado novamente.