# Listagem de diretório aparece com pontos, como remover?

Tags: php

Quero listar os arquivos de imagem de uma pasta, mas os dois primeiros links que são gerados aparecem assim:

```
<img class="mySlides" src="Arifureta-shokugyou/capitulo-2/." style="width:100%" />
<img class="mySlides" src="Arifureta-shokugyou/capitulo-2/.." style="width:100%" />
```

O resto aparece o link normal, mas os dois primeiros sempre aparecem com esse bug, que não sei como resolver.

Código:

```
<div class="w3-content" id="box-slider" style="max-width:800px">
    <img class="mySlides" src="public/assets/img/1.jpg" style="width:100%" />
<?php
$path = "Arifureta-shokugyou/capitulo-2/";
$diretorio = dir($path);
$diretorio = $diretorio;

while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
    $img = '<img class="mySlides" src="' . "$path" . "$arquivo" . '" style="width:100%" /> ';
echo $img;

}
$diretorio -> close();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Vou responder essa também

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não é bug, é assim mesmo.

Todo diretório tem uma entrada `.` que representa o nível atual e `..` que representa o anterior:

[image: Screenshot mostrando saída do comando dir, com as entradas em questão]

Se não quer mostrar estas entradas, basta por um a condição antes:

```
if( $arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..' )
```

Aplicado ao seu `while` (e dando uma simplificada):

```
while ($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()) {
    if ($arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..')
        echo '<img class="mySlides" src="'.$path.$arquivo.'" style="width:100%"> ';
}
```

Como você está lidando com arquivos, tem uma outra saída interessante:

```
while ($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()) {
    if (is_file($pasta.$arquivo))
         echo '<img class="mySlides" src="'.$path.$arquivo.'" style="width:100%"> ';
}
```

A função `is_file` retorna verdadeiro para diretórios apenas. Só precisa adaptar a variável que eu usei de exemplo (`$pasta`) para o caminho físico do arquivo.

Aqui mesmo no site tem uma outra opção, se quiser listar apenas determinadas extensões:

> [Listar arquivos de uma pasta / diretório em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108662/70)

Notas:

- Não tem sentido usar aspas em váriaveis como você fez, isto é inadequado:

  ```
  ... . "$path" . "$arquivo" . ...
  //    ^     ^   ^        ^        variáveis não precisam de aspas. Aspas fazem o parser
  //                                de string ser invocado desnecessariamente neste caso.
  ```
- Se está usando HTML5, não existe fechamento de tag:

  `style="width:100%" />` isso é XML/XHTML
  `style="width:100%">`   isso é HTML5

Comment: Bgd, funcionou.

Comment: bgd pelas notas, vou usar com sabedoria

Answer (score 1):

No PHP também temos a classe da SPL chamada `FileSystemIterator`, que usa um iterador para listar os diretórios de um arquivo.

Por padrão, o `FileSystemiterator` vem com um segundo parâmetro chamado `FileSysteIterator::SKIP_DOTS`.

Esqueleto do método:

```
public __construct ( string $path [, int $flags = FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO | FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS ] )
```

Esse "skip dots" faz com que os pontos sejam ignorados. Ele vem definido por padrão, mas você também pode passá-lo por argumento se desejar.

Veja um exemplo:

```
$iterator = new FileSystemIterator($path, FileSystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);


foreach($iterator as $file) {

    echo '<img class="mySlides" src="' . $path . $file->getFileName(), '" style="width: 100%%">';
}
```

Mas detalhes na documentaçao do PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php